# "showed positive reaction" or "showed a positive reaction" for repetitive times

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Do I need to use the indefinite article in the sentence below or can I omit it?

> In general, she showed **a** very positive reaction to any developments in
> the lessons throughout this year.

I guess I would definitely need that article for a one-time case, but here the student  repeatedly reacts in the same manner every lesson throughout the whole academic year.

Comment: You can omit the article, but then **reactions** must be plural. The sentence is rather awkward in other ways, though. "Reacted positively" is more clear and direct. And what do you mean by "any developments?" Lastly, "throughout **the [last] year** instead of "throughout this year."

Comment: @TypeIA – Thank you for your answer.
“_And what do you mean by "any developments?"_”
– By “any developments in the lessons” I mean any turn of the course of the lesson like switching from overview of the vocabulary from the previous lesson to learning some new vocabulary, switching from learning new vocabulary to watching some video containing that new vocabulary, switching from watching video to doing some role-play with the new vocabulary, switching from a role-play to a small test base on the new vocabulary, etc.

Comment: @TypeIA – 
“_Lastly, "throughout the [last] year instead of "throughout this year."_”
– But this comment is being written in the end of this academic year. It is already the end of this year, yet it’s not over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An Interesting question and I would suggest not the correct one**.

> In general, she showed **a** very positive reaction to any developments in the lessons throughout this year.

**Yes you need the  indefinite article** unless you rephrase the sentence as suggested in comments. However **you do not need the definite article** as the lessons are not specific.

In general, she showed **a** very positive reaction to any developments in **the** Maths lessons throughout this year.

Personally I do not like the **use of in when used for a duration**, during is much better, When we use in we **need to define the period** *"We're going to Italy in April"* When we do not define the period it sounds incorrect "in lessons"?? so to try to correct this "the" is incorrectly placed before the subject; "in the lessons"

> In general, she showed **a** very positive reaction to any developments  during lessons throughout this year.

or better still lets correct the tense, seize ownership of the lessons and get rid of the clutter; during (in) and throughout both relate to a period of time so we do not need both of them.

> In general, throughout this year she has shown **a** very positive reaction to any developments in her lessons.

---

What "any developments" may refer to I have no idea but as we are given no context I will assume this phrase is correct.

---

in preposition (DURING): during part or all of a period of time: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/during)

Examples

Some trees lose their leaves in (the) autumn.

I started working here in 2009.

Life in the 19th century was very different from what it is now.

Bye, see you in the morning (= tomorrow morning).

Comment: Thank you very much for a very informative and insightful answer. Please, tell me, can I still keep the Past Simple and not switch to Present Perfect (perhaps, by changing "this year" to "the year")?

Comment: Yes of course, as long as the who article is put in the appropriate tense. I was actually debating this but decided against it as it is not my article. However I think, from what you wrote in comments, that you should also consider the present continuous. "In general, throughout this year she has been showing very positive reactions to any developments in her lessons."

Comment: I see. Thank you!